# Converting Tensorflow Object Detection API model results into a mask tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

**The task:**

I'm trying to integrate a model trained and exported via the Tensorflow Object Detection API into a larger graph that will convert the model results into a detection mask; essentially a float32 tensor of the same (height x width) dimensions as the input image, wherein each value reflects the model's confidence that the corresponding pixel lies within the bounding box of a detected object.  This is very similar to the output of a segmentation network, except the output I'm looking for isn't of dimension (height x width x num_classes), it is of dimension (height x width), as if there is only a single class being detected.  I would like to do this entirely within a Tensorflow graph.

**How I'm trying to accomplish it:**

I'm trying to use tf.boolean_mask() and tf.foldl() to incrementally build the mask from the box bounds returned by the detection model.   Note that in this example the mask values are binary; to keep the question simple I took out the code that scales the results by the detection confidence.

```
 def __init__(self, graph_protobuf, threshold=0.6):
    #Import code omitted...
    #Grab the model detection results:
    boxes = tf.squeeze(detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0'), axis=0)
    scores = tf.squeeze(detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0'), axis=0)
    classes = tf.squeeze(detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0'), axis=0)
    num_detect = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('num_detections:0')
    #Only consider boxes above a provided threshold:
    over_threshold = tf.greater(scores, threshold)
    detections = tf.logical_and(over_threshold, tf.equal(classes, 1))

    #Debugging: Print out what the model result dimensions are.
    test = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')
    print("Shape of mask: {}  Shape of scores: {}   Shape of classes: {}  Raw score shape: {}".format(str(detections.shape), str(scores.shape), str(classes.shape), str(test.shape)))
    print("Boxes: {}".format(str(test)))

    #Remove under-threshold results:
    detection_boxes = tf.boolean_mask(boxes, detections)
    #Build the mask:
    self.result = tf.foldl(processBox, detection_boxes, initializer=tf.zeros([720,1280]))

 def processBox(self, res, box):
    res[box[0]:box[2],box[1]:box[3]].assign(tf.ones(((box[2]-box[0]),(box[3]-box[1]))))
```

**The problem:**

I think Tensorflow is having trouble with the unknown number of boxes returned by the model.   Here is the result of trying to use this graph:

```
 Shape of mask: <unknown>  Shape of scores: <unknown>   Shape of classes: <unknown>  Raw score shape: <unknown>
 Boxes: Tensor("detection_scores:0", dtype=float32)

 <...uninteresting stack trace omitted...>

 File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 1121, in boolean_mask
"Number of mask dimensions must be specified, even if some dimensions"
ValueError: Number of mask dimensions must be specified, even if some dimensions are None.  E.g. shape=[None] is ok, but shape=None is not.
```

Which is a complaint about tf.boolean_mask().   As you can see, at runtime I can't grab the model output dimensions at all.  tf.boolean_mask() works just fine with tf.constants as input, so this leads me to conclude that this approach may have some fundamental problems.

Is there a way to make this approach work?  If not, what is the right way to build the mask result I'm looking for?

Comment: Can you specify the shape of your placeholders?

Comment: Yes, I know what the shape of the image_tensor placeholder will be.

Comment: I think set_shape calls on them should fix this problem